# How to limit phpbb's search function

Tags: php, mysql, search, phpbb

I have a large phpbb forum that was recently dumped into my lap and the search function is really eating up my server resources.

I am looking for a way to stop the query after say 500 results. It is my understanding that the sql_query_limit function could take care of this issue but phpbb's search functions are above my knowledge level.

Any help being pointed in the correct direction is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

phpbb won't allow to search more than 50 results by default

Comment: Umm no....If that is true how am I able to get hundreds of results from my searches?

I want phpbb to stop querying the db after it gets say 500 results. I do not want to have it search the whole database but only display 50 results, that does not help the search function use less resources.